# Shadows sticking to sides of the site

Tags: html, css

I would like to put shadows to both sides of my site as you can see here - http://www.oztrik.sk/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/trik.jpg

I thought of putting them into left and right `divs` with `width:100%;` and `height:auto;`  as background images, `repeat-y`.

```
#left { background:url('../img/shadow_left.png') left center repeat-y; width:100%;     height:auto; float:left; }
#right { background:url('../img/shadow_right.png') right center repeat-y; width:100%; height:auto; float:right; }
```

The problem is when the `width` of the content `div` is bigger than the browser window size, the shadow stays stuck to the right side of the window and not to the right side of the page. When I put it to `auto`, the problem comes back the other way around.

Also, when the page is zoomed out, the shadow ends with the end of the content.

Any ideas how to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Are the `float`s necessary?  What happens if you remove them?  It seems like you have two mechanisms in place to position the shadows appropriately (full width with background alignment and the float).  Please include HTML.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend creating the shadows in CSS rather than with images [like in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/RKgXL/7/):

```
body {
    box-shadow: inset 100px 0 100px -100px #000,
                inset -100px 0 100px -100px #000;
}
```

For help with solving your specific implementation, please provide a live site or [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates the problem.

**Edit**

To get your implementation working, try this:

```
#left {
    background: url('../img/shadow_left.png') left center repeat-y;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#right {
    background: url('../img/shadow_right.png') right center repeat-y;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#center {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Notes:
 - For z-index to be rendered properly, the element must have a declared `position` property.
 - You should also change the `width` of `#left`, and `#right` to be the width of your shadow assets.
 - Make `#left`, `#right`, and `#center` all direct children of `#wrapper`

Comment: Thx, that's a great solution. Still, I would like to find a solution without CSS3.

The site is not live yet, I uploaded first test version here - http://www.oztrik.sk/test/

Comment: `box-shadow` is [fully supported by major rendering engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)#Properties) hence the removal of vendor prefixes. However if you would like to use images, see my edit for a possible solution.

Comment: Works, you made me happy this evening :-) Thx!

Comment: Nice.  Didn't know about `box-shadow`!